# Word for turning one's head suddenly

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word to describe the motion of suddenly and quickly turning one's head from fear and tension?

Eg. "*He ______ turned his head to look at where the sound had come from"*

Comment: Your sample sentence suggests that you are looking for a word that works *with* 'turned his head' and doesn't replace either turn of head. Is that right, you are looking for an adverb? In which case, what do you want it to tell the reader that 'suddenly' or 'quickly' doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the phrase *snapped his head*.

> **snap** *verb*
>   1.2 (*with complement or adverbial*) Move or alter with a brisk movement and typically a sharp sound.
>   ‘He was looking downward now, but, sensing the movement, his head snapped up.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snap)

Note that it isn't strictly necessary for *sound* to accompany the movement, as the selected example shows.

Your sentence would then be

- He snapped his head (up / to the side) to look at where the sound had come from.

Answer (score 0):

With  a little reworking, the sentence could be the following:

> **Startled**, he turned to see where the noise/sound had come from

Merriam-Webster

> [startled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/startle):  to move or jump suddenly (as in surprise or alarm)

Alternatively, the verb *jolt* could be used,

> His head **jolted** to where the sound came from

M-W

> [jolt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jolt): to cause to move with a sudden jerky motion

Answer (score 0):

Words you could use are spun, snapped, twisted, jerked, yanked and wrenched.

Comment: +1 for *spun* and *jerked (his head around)*.  Could also say ***swivelled (around)***.

Comment: With the example sentence, as written, though, none of these would fit. "He ______ **turned** his head to look at where the sound had come from". The fault may well be with the example, of course.

Comment: *Snapped* has already been suggested, *yanked* and *wrenched* do not work at all unless the protagonist was trapped in some way, or confined in a tight space, *jerk* almost works but implies involuntary action not volition, only *spun*, IMO, works. You should provide a dictionary definition.